How to remove bounce from floors?
We bought a new construction (built in 2022) last year. I have noticed that the floors in our kitchen / living area have a little bit more bounce than I would like - nothing crazy, but I can feel vibrations when someone walks by and sometimes hear a slight rattle when we have dishes on the table.
I'm wondering if the floor joists need reinforcement and if that would help reduce some of the bounce? Here are some additional details:
The areas with the most bounce sit on top of a pretty big unfinished basement.
The joists are 2x12, and spaced 16" on center
The span in some places is a wide as 16 feet - I believe the joists can handle this from a structural perspective, but maybe its causing some bounce?
There is one row of blocking added, about halfway across each span. However I noticed that the blocking is only hammered in, and not nailed/screwed. Not sure if this is a problem. Adding some pics of the joists / blocking here:
https://imgur.com/a/zjWjwuc
The sub floor is 3/4" plywood, and on top is hardwood floor.
Is there anything I can do to reduce some of the bounce and stiffen the floor? Would adding another row of blocking in each span help?
Any tips are appreciated, Thanks!

Unfinished basement below?
Add a beam and some posts/columns, or a load bearing wall, to reduce the span of the joists.
The wall may be the simpler/cheaper option, as it probably won't require new footings, since the load is spread and it should not be a lot of loading.
